# Permission Denied error if link clicked twice

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

im  looping through a list of elements (select, click link, save as). By some reason, when a link is clicked - save as dialog doesnt always appear (whether programmatically or manually clicked by mouse). So sometimes the link has to be clicked twice. Now the issue is - if i loop through the elements and click the link once, the code goes well, but not all files are saved. If i, however, run a code that clicks the link twice, I get Permission Denied (70) error. Ive seen ppl struggling with this error a lot here. Do you have any suggestions please?

In the code below this is the part of the condition that is of interest and with only one click (+application wait) as below the code work well. With the 2 lines uncommented it breaks with error.

```
                Else
                    Set l = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") 'getElementsByClassName("MainContent") '.getElementsByTagName("a") '.getelementbyid("ctl00_MainContent_ValidationSummary1")
                        For Each el In l
                            If el.innerText = "View Bill" Then
                            el.Click
'                            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
'                            el.Click
                            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
                            Exit For
                            'IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "submitTransForm()", JavaScript
                            Else
                            End If
                        Next el
                End If
```

Comment: If you click the links manually, does the save-as dialog menu pop up every time?  If so then there might be something in the page background like json or javascript code....  And if that's true then you'll have to find a way to execute what ever firing code that is with application.execute command

Comment: no, it doesnt. so it doesnt depend if the link is clicked by code or manually

Comment: Can you share the website so I can take a look at it and try to find a solution?

Comment: I can paste some source code (as attachment? not sure how). webpage requires login/pass which i cant share

Comment: Let me ask this:  does the same button sometimes open the save box when you click once but also sometimes you need to click twice on that same link to open the save box?  Or do the same links require two clicks all the time?  I notice you've got wait times in there.  Maybe sometimes the page's server runs more slowly than other times and it just appears that it didn't recognize the first click.  Have you tried putting a pause at the first line of the For loop and stepping through with PF8, waiting about 10 to 15 seconds for each step?  Try to look and see if it actually performs the first clik

Comment: to be uberprecise - its a link, not a button; pressing the same link sometimes opens the open/save dialog, sometimes it doesnt, so i have to press once again (whether with code or manually); the code above does 2 clicks all the time, because it was my "dirty" solution, as i couldnt figure out how to check if open/save dialog is open in explorer (that ribbon at the bottom with open - save/saveas - cancel);

Comment: ive tried waiting more - no use, its not that the page loads slowly, sometimes if i click - the page (or save as dialog in this case) doesnt start loading at all; ive gone through this part of the code with F8, same result - no saveas dialog

Comment: I would advise to try your code on some random other pages without the second click, just to see if your code is somehow buggy.  (Though it looks ok to me.)  Sometimes looks are deceiving.  If it requires two clicks on a link on a google search page then you will know it is your code.  Otherwise it must be something in the website's code.  I suspect the latter but we don't know until we try.